# Show synonym suggestions awaiting my vote

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, tag-synonyms

[Tag synonym suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested&tab=newest) are starting to explode.  It would be easier to vote if I could have a single page that filtered out suggestions I've already acted upon or could not act upon (i.e. my own).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just made a major couple of changes that will greatly simplify this.

We have been noticing a large volume of invalid suggestions, to combat this:

1. I changed it so you need a score of 10 or more on answers for the tag, to participate in the tag synonym creation process (proposal and voting)
2. I changed the "suggested" filter on the UI to filter out all suggestions you are unable to vote on. (note: it will still show ones you have voted on, but the list should be pretty small - so I do not anticipate this being a problem)

I think this will greatly help dealing with this.

Comment: I think #1 might be counter-productive.  I can spot (and thus propose and vote on) many tags that should be synonyms without having participated in those tags, plus many users don't seem to participate in the synonym process at all.  Perhaps limit voting (but not proposal) to those with a score in that tag?  Or perhaps include experience in the SE site as a whole, as measured by having 4k or more rep?  The latter could be useful to add as a privilege that can then introduce users to synonyms.

Comment: (An example for the first comment is when I consolidated tags on Meta for [editing-badges], [publicity-badges], and [reputation-cap-badges].)

Comment: @waffles: Another case on SO: [ms-project] and [microsoft-project] should be synonyms, yet I can't propose it.  Should I post a retag-request on meta?

Comment: @Gnome, the thing is that mods have been drowning in the backlog, tag synonyms are for major issues ... if we go with tag synonyms for every tiny tag we will drown in synonym management.

Comment: @waffles: I'm not sure what the best solution is.  I've been proposing synonyms instead of posting [retag-requests] on meta (thinking it is the better solution), believing that I can spot (what I'd consider) clear-cut cases (microsoft-project vs ms-project, above) and voting can sort it out, while consensus seems to be that mass-retagging is discouraged (even when the number is low enough, here ms-project's ~50 uses is pushing it).

Comment: @waffles: Perhaps looking at this from another angle would help: [microsoft-project] vs [ms-project] isn't a "huge" issue, but *should* it be resolved, or should the tags remain fractured?  I've been operating under the assumption that resolving the tags would be a worthwhile improvement.

Comment: @Gnome, I think this kind of calls for a meta topic to discuss ... "in light of the rule changes - what are we supposed to do" - I am not totally against adjusting rules, just want to find a happy balance

Comment: (For anyone reading comments, someone has [requested the above](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69588/drop-the-score-requirement-for-proposing-tag-synonyms-atleast-for-super-user).)

Answer (score 6):

Something different, I personally hate the UI of the synonyms overview. I'd love to vote some of them, but to do that I have to click every master tag open in a new tab (because there's no link to go back to the synonyms page other than the browser back button). That's too much clicks forward and back. It would be a *great* improvement if the synonyms overview itself also contains the vote buttons in the synonym column.

Comment: I agree with you, currently, but if [more discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64249/show-linked-pages-or-wiki-on-each-tags-synonym-page) was available, it could be useful to prompt people to at least see that before voting.  (Then again, I'm used to having 60+ tabs open at once. :P)

Comment: Making it take time to vote, may make people think more about how they are voting.

Answer (score 3):

Please oh Please, make it easier to vote on the Tag Synonyms.  It's **mouse-click hell**.

Answer (score 1):

I would like a page that showed all tag where I have answered or asked a question that includes the tag on at least one side of the synonym.

I cannot give good input on tags I have never experienced, so would like to direct my efforts to where it is most useful.  Ideally the page should be sorted to the newest proposed tag synonym is at the top.