# Show linked pages or wiki on each tag's synonym page

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, tag-synonyms

It's hard to discuss synonym suggestions.  There may be multiple viewpoints and confusion to be ironed out, yet all we can do is vote or tediously track down the suggestor and hope they provided contact details.  (Or find a random post and comment to them.)

Meta is the right place to discuss synonyms, but you can't find those discussions when looking at the suggestions (i.e. .../tags/XXX/synonym pages).

Similar to the "linked" sidebar on questions, could tag synonyms indicate what Meta posts discuss them?  This is slightly different from current use of "linked", principally because it would require working *across* sites.

Instead, could there be a smallish wiki section on tag synonyms to list links?  (And other info?  Not sure what would be appropriate there—discussion about rationale would be better in a Meta post.)  This would allow linking to discussion from *any* SE site (e.g. back to a meta.SO post when the same rationale applies to a [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) tag).

The automatic "linked" list is preferable, if it can be done across the SE network (possibly only to meta.* sites?), rather than manually (i.e. not) updating a wiki.  But it seems the former feature requires more thought (and could be useful in other areas), while the latter could be a useful stopgap.

Comment: Where ever the discussion occurs it should allow people with a lower rep to give input. I don't mind (much) that I can't vote on synonyms now, but I would like to be able to more easily suggest and discuss them.

Comment: @Mark: You can discuss (and even initially suggest) on meta sites, and I'd like the synonym page to somehow link to such discussion.  I just don't know how to best implement that (i.e. automatic "linked" section and/or smallish wiki); mostly because I don't know the overall direction intended nor the implementation details.