# New View of Unvoted Tag Synonym Suggestions

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, voting, tag-synonyms

It would be really nice if we could get a view where it showed only the Synonyms that we haven't voted on (the individual user hasn't voted on).

So something just like this [Suggested Synonym view](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested), but also filtered for the ones I haven't voted up or down yet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show synonym suggestions awaiting my vote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64247/show-synonym-suggestions-awaiting-my-vote)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: [Show synonym suggestions awaiting my vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64247/show-synonym-suggestions-awaiting-my-vote/69190#69190)

The semantics of "suggested" has been altered only to include suggestions you can act on.