# Why am I not allowed to propose a tag synonym?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tag-synonyms, superuser

Why am I not allowed to propose a tag synonym on Super User? I have 10k+ rep, the privileges show 100% across all - what am I missing out on ?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it is because one of the requirements for proposing a synonym is that you have to have a score of <s>10</s> 3 or more in that tag.

I don't have enough reputation to see the [vote breakdowns](https://superuser.com/search?q=[bookmarks]+user%3A4377), but I think you only have 6.

Comment: I seemed to have skipped reading the score of 10  part, thanks.

Comment: @Sathya: That requirement was [recently added](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64247/show-synonym-suggestions-awaiting-my-vote/69190#69190).