# Allow moderators to see the full list of suggested synonyms

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-synonyms, moderators

Recently, [the tag synonyms were changed so that people cannot participate in tag synonyms without a requisite amount of participation in the tag itself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64247/show-synonym-suggestions-awaiting-my-vote/69190#69190). To complement it, the `suggested` view filters out things you can't vote on.

Unfortunately, this only measures on tag participation and ignores the diamonds who can both vote on synonyms *and* approve them straight up. I regularly check the suggested view in order to see what might need hasty votes or what I simply might agree with. But now I can't see anything. So even though looking at `all` shows me a bunch of pending synonyms...

[image: There's 6 of them there and a lot more down the page.]

...looking under `suggested` gives me a perplexing emptiness.

[image: Actually, that should be a blank box, because the box is as empty as the page. But I'm too lazy.]

Can we change it so that since diamonds actually *can* vote on those tag synonyms, that they can see all of them?

Comment: +1 for the freehand Mario `[?]` block!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

will be fixed today ... moderators will be able to see all suggestions