# How to add synonym to a tag if nobody has enough reputation on that tag?

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms

**How is it possible to add synonym to a tag if nobody has enough reputation on that particular tag (yet)?**

To be more specific, I noticed that there are "*websocket*" and "*websockets*" tags. They have 160 questions and 15 questions, respectively. It would make sense to make "*websockets*" a synonym of "*websocket*".

At the same time, the top scores page shows that "*all time top user*" has a score of 27 - quite far off from the required 2500.

**So, what is the procedure in this case? Post the "add synonym" proposal here, on meta?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep
that's pretty much all we can do for now. That way a diamond mod will hopefully see it and create the synonym.

I voiced [the plural issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70033/lower-the-rep-vote-requirement-or-automatically-accept-plural-synonyms-on-su) before and it looks promising.