# Pending tag synonyms not reported in suggested tab

Tags: bug, tag-synonyms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tag synonyms Suggested tab isn't showing all pending proposals](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71468/tag-synonyms-suggested-tab-isnt-showing-all-pending-proposals)

There is a pending tab synonym suggestion in [the full list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=all):

[image]

But it isn't reported in the [suggestion list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested):

[image]