# Suggested synonyms not showing proposals I could vote on

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I've seen [Tag synonyms Suggested tab isn't showing all pending proposals](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71468/tag-synonyms-suggested-tab-isnt-showing-all-pending-proposals) and I know that the "suggested" tab is only supposed to show the proposals that I can vote on. However, that tab is currently empty for me and I don't think that it should be.

There is an active synonym proposal for [css](/questions/tagged/css) that I can vote on (tried it, works indeed). There are also two of my own proposals - a few days ago these were shown in the "suggested" tab, now I no longer see them there. Not seeing my proposals is actually understandable and could be a bug fix because I cannot vote on them. But I don't see why the [css](/questions/tagged/css) synonym proposal wouldn't show up in the "suggested" tab.

[image: screenshots]

<sub>I hope my illustration meets the style expectations for MSO. I tried...</sub>

Comment: The illustration meets all my expectations ... thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regression, will be fixed in the next deploy. Thanks for catching it.

For context see [my blog post](http://samsaffron.com/archive/2011/09/05/Digging+ourselves+out+of+the+mess+Linq-2-SQL+created)

Comment: Confirmed, works correctly now.