# Rename a tag which is spelled wrongly

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request

The emphasis on reputation points seems to be overused in this situation.
There is a tag named 'heirarchy' - which is just a mis-spelling.
Apparently, I need 2500 reputation points merely to suggest anything.

What am I expected to do at this point? Write an email, forget about it, leave it up to someone else?

That I couldn't figure it out means it's probably not going to happen.
But I'm interested to know what you're expecting.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.  I merged all questions into the correct spelling of the tag.

Comment: Thanks @Bill. Could you push through the synonym?

Comment: @Jon: I voted for it and was surprised to find that it didn't get pushed through automatically.  I'm searching for the option now in the moderator tools.  :)  (Found it!)

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: There's a bug there; you have to select the "All" tab to see it unless you have enough rep in the hierarchy tag. See [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69439/allow-moderators-to-see-the-full-list-of-suggested-synonyms) (thanks to Grace Note for the link).

Comment: @Michael: Thank you.  That had me confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have proposed [heirarchy](/questions/tagged/heirarchy) as a synonym of [hierarchy](/questions/tagged/hierarchy).

This will avoid any confusion in the future.

---

If you don't have enough rep to do something in the system that you think should be done (that isn't something like "could you vote to close this for me" sort of thing), it's completely appropriate to post here on Meta like you did.

Comment: Ha, I can't vote the synonym up because I don't have enough upvotes in the hierarchy tag.  How did you even make the proposal?

Comment: @jjn: The only restriction on proposing is rep (2500). To vote you need to have upvotes.