# How to fix a typo in a tag?

Tags: support, retag-request

Sorry if I'm missing something obvious.

There's "[presentmodalviewcontrolle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/presentmodalviewcontrolle)" tag on SO, with an obviously missing "r". My privileges allow me only to *suggest a synonym* (or I just miserably failed to find a documented way to edit the tag). Anyway, I have read [a similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72968/rename-a-tag-which-is-spelled-wrongly) on Meta, but the accepted answer merely seems to suggest that we suggest a synonym. In this case the typo seems to be too trivial to deserve synonyms, it just needs to be corrected.

Is the best practice really to report such things on Meta and be done with them? If so, can anybody with enough privileges correct the typo, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can't actually be corrected, at least not the ideal way you probably want. Tags have a maximum length of 25 characters, and "presentmodalviewcontrolle" happens to be exactly that.

It must either be reduced to a shorter tag entirely, or swapped for an existing tag that conveys a more general essence of the same item.

Comment: How about "present-mvc"?

Comment: @Grace Note, Ouch. What a mishap. OK, "modalviewcontroller" seems like an excellent candidate. Thanks a lot for the information.

Comment: Hmm, "present-mvc" looks good too.

Comment: Haha, I can't suggest a synonym because I don't have enough score for the tag. Help still needed.

Comment: @Billy, assuming it's really "modal" rather than "model", then I'd suggest to NOT use "mvc". (If not, then there's 2 typos?)

Comment: @Arjan It's really "presentModalViewController", a UIKit message for modal views. MVC does, indeed, trigger a wrong neuron.

Comment: [nsfetchedresultscontrolle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nsfetchedresultscontrolle) has the same problem. I blame Apple.

Comment: @Arjan: Oops. Misread that :P