# Tag typo: html-spcecial-characters

Tags: support, retag-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix a typo in a tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77993/how-to-fix-a-typo-in-a-tag)

I don't have enough rep to fix [html-spcecial-characters](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/html-spcecial-characters/).

It's not an obvious synonym of [htmlspecialchars](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/htmlspecialchars/info) as currently defined; there are some questions about the php function and others more generally about HTML character escaping.

Comment: It's not actually. [tag:htmlspecialchars] is specifically for the PHP function (according to it's wiki description at least). I've replaced [tag:html-spcecial-characters] with [tag:htmlspecialchars] on the questions which were about PHP, but left the rest.

Comment: [tag:html-entities] seem a better match for the remaining questions...

Comment: One of them, I just took out, it doesn't need to be there. Anyway, it's gone now.