# Deleting misspelt tags

Tags: support, tags, tag-deletion

Under the [newest tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=new) section of Stackoverflow, I found the tags [elipse](/questions/tagged/elipse) and [javascrpt](/questions/tagged/javascrpt) which are likely to have been created as a result of a typo. Is there a way to suggest removal of such tags? If so, where? And how much rep is required for that privilege? I don't think suggesting a synonym would be appropriate in such a case.

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/72969/179331), it looks like the only recourse for me is to report such instances in meta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These tags have no questions attached to them. They will be automatically removed within 24 hours in that case.

If there would be a few questions having these tags, it would be appropriate to retag them correctly. And then the tags will be removed within 24 hours.

Comment: I had edited the question which had the `elipse` tag and retagged it. That's why there are no questions now under it.

Comment: @DheerajV.S. yep that's what we should do on such cases. Well done! :)