# Tag containing a typo - should it be deleted?

Tags: discussion, retag-request

I just stumbled on the [sql-srever](/questions/tagged/sql-srever) on SO. I think it is just a typo and thus it should be deleted.

Comment: Ah! I didn't know the term "zombie tag". Should I delete this question now?

Comment: My take - tweak the question title to something akin to "some tag has a typo - it should be deleted" so that when someone else doesn't know the 'zombie tag' term, they find this which leads them there.

Comment: @MichaelT Thanks for the tip! Edited the title.

Comment: @MichaelT Or just update the FAQ question. ;)

Comment: @animuson well, there's that too... There's also another viable dupe chain of [Deleting misspelt tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160248/deleting-misspelt-tags) which leads to [What *currently* happens to zombie tags?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40724/what-currently-happens-to-zombie-tags) which leads to the faq.  Naming the FAQ well is a good thing, having good dup signposts to the question are also good... and this is one that people will likely stumble upon when looking for the ultimate answer... (to life, the universe, and everything?).