# Drop the score requirement for proposing tag synonyms (atleast for Super User)

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, tag-synonyms

Related to : [Why am I not allowed to propose a tag synonym ?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1653/why-am-i-not-allowed-to-propose-a-tag-synonym)

Couple of days ago, there were certain changes done to the requirements of [who can propose synonyms.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64247/show-synonym-suggestions-awaiting-my-vote/69190#69190)

> So you need a **score of 10 or more on answers for the tag**, to participate in the tag synonym creation process (proposal and voting)

I'm getting real annoyed by those <strike>stupid</strike> synonym proposal changes.

Latest example: 
[`[Popups]`](https://superuser.com/tags/popups) ( 33 questions ) v/s [`[Popup]`](https://superuser.com/tags/popup) ( 2 questions ).

So I went over to propose a synonym.

[image: But NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO!]

Now either I let it remain as it is, or I have to go and manually retag them. And that means bumping the questions up. 
When there's a rep requirement, I don't know why in the world there's a score requirement. I realize that more the score == better participation in the tagged questions.

This makes sense for Stack Overflow, or ( perhaps ) Server Fault, but this is counter-productive in Super User. There are just not enough people on Super User who have the required score.

The third option is to raise a question in Meta and ask a question and wait for a Moderator or some one else who has sufficient score in those tagged questions ( hmm .. any way to find out WHO exactly? ) to propose and vote for it.. This just makes no sense - considering that the whole point of synonyms was to reduce the manual editing and bumping up.

Comment: Related comments at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64247/show-synonym-suggestions-awaiting-my-vote/69190#69190

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I improved the error message and dropped the requirement down to 3 score. Ultimately I think this req should scale to the # of questions in the tag.

Comment: It should scale to the number of questions on the tag. Reducing the score isn't of much help. @waffles' suggestion is a better alternative.

Comment: I just noticed that most of the [binding] questions seem to actually be [databinding] questions,
however I get a message that I need at least "5 score in this tag", which I believe I DO have
(after retagging existing [binding] questions I've answered).

Can the system be adjusted to include the synonym score and not just the master score?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not against dropping the score required to propose down to 1 or even 0, but I think the score required to vote should remain at 10. That way at least mods can look at the proposal.

Too many crappy synonyms were getting approved on SO and it became a maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score 2):

Would it not make sense to ignore the score requirement for 10k and above users - if a user has 10k rep then they can probably be trusted to have done their homework before suggesting a tag synonym.

Comment: I have not found this to be true