# Allow tag synonym suggestion past a certain rep point

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tag-synonyms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we allow 7.5K users  to suggest tag synonyms without a score of 5 in the tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103211/can-we-allow-7-5k-users-to-suggest-tag-synonyms-without-a-score-of-5-in-the-tag)

As it is, suggesting a tag synonym requires a score of 5 in the tag. Can a privilege be added, say as part of Trusted User, that allows users with sufficient privileges to suggest synonyms as well as users with a score of 5 or more in the tag?

Tag synonyms are often obvious, and I think the 20k Trusted Users should be... trusted... to be able to differentiate between tags. After all, it takes more votes after the suggestion to approve it anyway.

Comment: Wouldn't that actually *reduce* the number of people who can do this? Also, as someone in the vague realm of 20k, I can tell you that by the time I reach 20k, I would have no business suggesting synonyms for tags I have no points in. (It occurs to me maybe you mean "in addition to" and not "instead of", but still!)

Comment: And that synonym you propose is not a good example. There are other (valid on SO) meanings to canvas. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119496/html5-canvas-tag-should-be-a-synonym-of-the-canvas-tag, so ...

Comment: @AndrewBarber: Would you say [tag:dto] and [tag:data-transfer-object] are synonyms? You have no points in [tag:dto], but the wiki specifically states that it means [tag:data-transfer-object]. (And yes, that would decrease the number. I'll change it to a union.)

Comment: @Mat: It's part of the wiki. You're right, I'll just change that.