# Tag Synonym Proposal - Rep Requirement

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, tag-synonyms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we allow 7.5K users  to suggest tag synonyms without a score of 5 in the tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103211/can-we-allow-7-5k-users-to-suggest-tag-synonyms-without-a-score-of-5-in-the-tag)

Is the reputation for proposing a tag synonym really necessary?

I ask because sometimes there are easy synonyms I spot, especially in regards to the categorization of new technologies (knockout => knockout-js => knockoutjs) that are easy to point out. But you have to have rep with the tag that you are trying to associate a synonym with. It seems inhibiting since they still need to go through an approval process.

It would make sense if you were able to approve it on your own.

Perhaps the overall reputation minimum is enough?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can we allow 7.5K users  to suggest tag synonyms without a score of 5 in the tag?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103211/can-we-allow-7-5k-users-to-suggest-tag-synonyms-without-a-score-of-5-in-the-tag), [Add the ability to create any tag synonym to the “trusted user” privileges](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79151/add-the-ability-to-create-any-tag-synonym-to-the-trusted-user-privileges), [Allow tag synonym suggestion past a certain rep point](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121358/allow-tag-synonym-suggestion-past-a-certain-rep-point)

Answer (score 0):

If think - yes, it's some sign of your skills and (from other side) "Reputation" serves as reputation and credit-history