# Should tag synonyms be automatically retagged to the master tag?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms

This is a followup of [Gilles' comment here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012#comment361686_130691).

As as result of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012, a lot of questions were being retagged. I'll focus on the [assembly](/questions/tagged/assembly) tag, but I suppose the problem applies to other tags as well.

---

Originally, the [assembly](/questions/tagged/assembly) tag, was supposed to be disambiguated between [assembly-language](/questions/tagged/assembly-language) and [.net-assembly](/questions/tagged/.net-assembly). This resulted in about 80 of the top [assembly](/questions/tagged/assembly) questions being retagged as [assembly-language](/questions/tagged/assembly-language).

Then later, [assembly-language](/questions/tagged/assembly-language) was simply made a synonym of [assembly](/questions/tagged/assembly). I expected that all  [assembly-language](/questions/tagged/assembly-language) would eventually be (automatically) be retagged to [assembly](/questions/tagged/assembly) (and thus) merging the vote counts.

However it's been well over 24 hours and [assembly](/questions/tagged/assembly) and [assembly-language](/questions/tagged/assembly-language) have not been merged.

[image]

1. When you search for the [assembly](/questions/tagged/assembly) tag none of the top assembly questions show up because they have all been retagged as [assembly-language](/questions/tagged/assembly-language).
2. When you search for the [assembly-language](/questions/tagged/assembly-language) tag, it redirects to the [assembly](/questions/tagged/assembly) tag.

Here's a few bigger examples that were retagged [assembly](/questions/tagged/assembly) -> [assembly-language](/questions/tagged/assembly-language):

- [When is assembler faster than C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577554/when-is-assembler-faster-than-c)
- [How do I achieve the theoretical maximum of 4 FLOPs per cycle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389648/how-to-achieve-4-flops-per-cycle)
- [Why does GCC generate such radically different assembly for nearly the same C code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10250419/why-does-gcc-generate-such-radically-different-assembly-for-nearly-the-same-c-co)
- [Is 'switch' faster than 'if'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805026/is-switch-faster-than-if)

There's a lot more of them. But they're hard to find since searches for [assembly-language](/questions/tagged/assembly-language) redirects to [assembly](/questions/tagged/assembly).

---

**How should we handle this situation?** Do we manually find all the questions tagged [assembly-language](/questions/tagged/assembly-language) and retag them back to [assembly](/questions/tagged/assembly)?

Or is there some other (possibly moderator/dev-only) process that I'm not aware of? Or have I simply not waited long enough?

Comment: I have no idea whether to tag this as [meta-tag:support], [meta-tag:feature-request], or [meta-tag:bug].

Comment: Definitely [meta-tag:feature-request]

Answer (score 6):

Moderators can already merge tags, so you just need to bring this to the attention of a mod and request that they merge the tags.

The merge isn't easily reversible, so it is unlikely that this tool will be automated or made available to non-moderators.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Since this is already on meta, I'll just wait for a mod to merge [tag:assembly-language] into [tag:assembly] and `[status-declined]` this particular feature request.