# Confusion over assembly tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

In the description for the [assembly](/questions/tagged/assembly) tag, it says to not use it and instead use [assembly-language](/questions/tagged/assembly-language) for low-level native PC instructions in order to distinguish from .NET bytecode questions.

However, when I retag a question from [assembly](/questions/tagged/assembly) to [assembly-language](/questions/tagged/assembly-language), it switches back to [assembly](/questions/tagged/assembly). Am I missing something here?

Comment: See this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131506/should-tag-synonyms-be-automatically-retagged-to-the-master-tag

Basically some confusion arose from the [ongoing tag cleanup](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012).

Comment: I suppose I should just not bother with retagging asm, then? I understand tags can have synonyms, but if that's the case I don't get why/how the master tag says that it's not to be used.

Comment: AFAIK, all the .NET stuff has been weeded out of the [tag:assembly] tag. So now we just need a moderator to merge [tag:assembly-language] into [tag:assembly].

Comment: And to get rid of the "don't use" description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That notice has now been removed from the tag wiki.