# Can [bool] be merged with (or made a synonym for?) [boolean]

Tags: discussion, tags, reputation, synonym-request

I do not think there is value in differentiating [bool](/questions/tagged/bool) and [boolean](/questions/tagged/boolean).  I note there is a distinction between "int" (limited range, overflowing) and "integer" (abstract mathematical concept)...but none between "float" and "floating-point" (perhaps there should be "real-number"?)

There are some questions with titles to the effect of *"is there a difference between bool and boolean"*.  But they seem to be language-specific, and I doubt there's much discernment in using the tags in the general case.  Examples of the few specific differentiating discussions, which I think would be fine tagged merely by "boolean" and the appropriate language tag:

[What is the difference between bool and Boolean types in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134746/what-is-the-difference-between-bool-and-boolean-types-in-c-sharp)

[Is there any difference between BOOL and Boolean in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016846/is-there-any-difference-between-bool-and-boolean-in-objective-c)

[Differences among various bool types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450117/difference-among-bool-boolean-and-boolean-in-java-android)

Sidenote: I am asking this question here in part to draw increased attention to the rather silly requirement of having 5 reputation in this tag to use the automated tag synonym suggestion mechanism:

[Can we allow 7.5K users  to suggest tag synonyms without a score of 5 in the tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103211/can-we-allow-7-5k-users-to-suggest-tag-synonyms-without-a-score-of-5-in-the-tag)

Logically speaking (er...pun intended?) it would seem that whatever reputation it takes to retag a bunch of questions manually should be greater than or equal to the reputation to make a tag synonym suggestion.  In a system that can triage wiki-like suggested anonymous edits from the Interweb, why would a tag synonym *suggestion* trigger a "nope, you can't do that" dialog to someone who can retag?

Then again, discussion is good.

Comment: I do wonder, though... is this 5 rep limit a litmus test of when a tag might be esoteric/abstract/tangential enough to need a discussion...and hence a post?  If that's the case, then explicitly pointing people here and nicely saying *"Hmmm...you don't have rep in this tag...but you think it's a synonym?  That means this might be a weird/abstract one.  We'd rather you write a reasoned retag argument on meta, click here to start one.  Here are some good examples..."*  The "I'm sorry Dave, I can't do that" response feels like a bit of a brick wall.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/boolean/synonyms - synonym suggested.

Comment: `We'd rather you write a reasoned retag argument on meta` -- Seems you figured this out already.

Answer (score -4):

Negative.

`bool` is a keyword in some programming languages, including C#.

`boolean` is a more general term, referring to any constant or variable that can contain one of only two possible values.

Comment: Per my argument above, that would suggest that `float` and `floating-point` should be distinct and yet float was deprecated...it is hard to imagine what the difference between tagging (`c#` `boolean`) and (`c#` `bool`) really adds.  To make an effective counterargument I'd think you'd have to find some questions for which this makes sense.

Comment: @HostileFork: I don't think `float` should have been deprecated.

Comment: I assume it's in a transitional phase to a synonym itself (?)...dunno the background.  But I feel like tags are supposed to be cross-cutting conceptual things you use to explore topics, and if a language like Rebol uses `logic!` for its true/false type and C++ uses `bool` and C sometimes has `typedef xxx BOOL` (Caps tags vs lower?) then the value emerges from using the formal *"there's a wiki article about it"* name of the concept across all languages instead of just parroting the keyword in each individual language.  Again, the challenge is "find questions where the distinction has value".

Comment: I don't have a problem with that, per se. But the community has been pushing for *more specific* tags for awhile now, not less specific ones. So I don't know how that jibes. I do know that keyword-specific and method-specific questions are (relatively) common, and that there are tags for them.

Comment: Admittedly a slippery slope...because then you get to umbrella terms like `boolean-logic` which suddenly drives the scope more broadly than just the nature of a boolean type or value (narrow things like "how many bits does a boolean take up in a structure?")  But there are sweet spots that are arbitrary...like 5 tags per question, for instance...and I think the bool/boolean is just one of those.  A tag that *isn't* used meaningfully for distinction *in practice* does more harm than good.

Comment: Some languages, e.g. Java, use `boolean` as the built-in type name. I do not think `bool` is an appropriately generic name for booleans-as-language-element.

Comment: @KevinReid Yup I'd be suggesting `bool` as a synonym for `boolean` (and not vice-versa).  *At least, my understanding of tag synonyms is that there is one tag that is the "canon" that shows up in the listings.*