# Synonymize the [rdp] and [remote-desktop] tags on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

Stack Overflow has at least two different tags referring to Microsoft's Remote Desktop Protocol:

- [rdp](/questions/tagged/rdp)
- [remote-desktop](/questions/tagged/remote-desktop)

I suppose you could argue that the former refers to the *protocol*, while the second refers to the client or something else more general, but I don't think is is a useful distinction for a programming site. It's also not like there are so many questions on this topic that you need a finer degree of distinction. Anyone who is interested in one tag will naturally be interested in the other. And any question that requires one tag should probably have (or at least fits well with) the other tag.

Providing further justification for this synonym, the tag wiki excerpts for both of these tags are *exactly the same*. The [rdp](/questions/tagged/rdp) tag has a full tag wiki, but I think that [remote-desktop](/questions/tagged/remote-desktop) should be made the "master" tag because it is more self-descriptive.

Comment: ...still waiting for [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103211/can-we-allow-7-5k-users-to-suggest-tag-synonyms-without-a-score-of-5-in-the-tag) to get implemented...

Comment: Along with that, most of them can be migrated to SuperUser

Comment: @hjpotter92 Maybe *some* of them can, but not all questions with this tag should be migrated. If they have to do with programming, they belong on SO.

Comment: You started with the first page, I started with the [last](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/remote-desktop?page=11&sort=newest&pagesize=50)

Comment: Hmm yeah, those are all too old to migrate. But I just put a huge dent in my daily close-vote allotment. Perhaps we can get a diamond with a few minutes to spare?