# Allow Question Votes to count for tag synonym suggestions

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms

*NOTE: [Can we allow 7.5K users  to suggest tag synonyms without a score of 5 in the tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/103211/16241) is a request for total rep to unlock synonym suggesting.*

***This is not the same feature request.***  This is a request to have Question Votes count toward the synonym suggestion total (rather than just answer votes).

I ask a lot of questions.  Like any good question asker, I research my question before asking it.  (However, I don't so so much research that I am ready to jump in and start answering questions.)

When I finally get around to asking my question, I frequently note that the phrase that is most commonly used to refer to a topic is not a tag.  After some searching, I find the right tag and I think "I would like to help out the next asker by putting a synonym on this tag".

But even if my questions get some up-votes, I can't help out like this.

It seems a bit backwards to me to have the answerers being the only ones who can suggest synonyms.  The anwerers KNOW their tag(s).  They don't need any synonyms (so they are less likely to suggest them).

It is the question asker that needs the synonym (so that they can get their question on the right tag).  Because the asker needs the synonym, they are the most likely to identify a missing one.

So, I would like to suggest this feature request:

- Allow askers with X number of question up-votes in a tag (or just # of questions asked) to SUGGEST synonyms.
- Don't allow them to vote on synonyms, because they are not the authority (like the answerers are).

Comment: Given how little attention the tag synonym handling system gets, and how unintuitive it is to get the a page where you can actually do something about them, I don't think this is worth it. Synonym proposals can stay pretty much forever in the system with no attention. The system needs a complete rethink.