# What is a good work flow for creating bilingual tag synonyms?

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

When I create a new tag at a SE language site, I have trouble setting up the synonym relationship with its bilingual equivalent.

Suppose I notice that a bunch of existing questions are about a particular grammatical topic, but we didn't yet have an appropriate tag for that topic.  I have enough rep to create a tag, and I can go through the relevant questions and start adding the new tag; but I get hung up at the stage of creating the *synonym* in the other language.  In other words: suppose I create the new tag in Spanish.  I would also like to create a tag in English for that same topic, and I'd like to set up the synonym relationship.  This has always proved messy, largely because of the requirement to have a minimum score in that tag.

Sooner or later I end up posting in Meta to request moderator assistance, but this is not a great solution because it clogs up our Meta and the overstretched moderators start feeling swamped.

What is an effective, smooth, efficient work flow for non-moderators to create bilingual tag pairs?  The tag synonym system appears to have been invented for general use, not for language sites which have a significant learner sub-community which needs all the tags to be available in English as well.

---

**Edit**: Related post: [Can we allow 7.5K users  to suggest tag synonyms without a score of 5 in the tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/103211/287826)

Comment: It is funny you mention we mods in Spanish.SE are overstretched and start feeling swamped, when [such requests](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2895/1674) were done quite fast. Also, I do not see the point of trying to get Meta.SE attention on a Spanish.SE issue, when the issue seems to be that we (I) just asked you to hold on on asking so many questions on tags (not about creating synonyms, but about others), so that the community has time to express their point of view before jumping to the next one.

Comment: @fedorqui - Exactly.  Clearly, posting every little tag issue on Meta is not a great work flow.  I am seeking a better way.  Perhaps folks from the many other language sites will have a suggestion, and if not, perhaps someone will have an idea for a feature request.

Comment: On some of the sites I mod, people who were keen to get a bunch of synonyms sorted put in the work to list them all in one post, along with exactly what was needed. The community voted on them. And then the mods went in and implemented the changes in a big batch.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The whole tag synonym process is a hassle. **There is no good way for regular** (i.e. non-mod) **users to create tag synonyms**. There is a "bad" way (it's actually borderline abusive and I wouldn't recommend it): find any answer of yours with a score of 5 or more, retag the question to include the tag, go and create or vote on the synonym, and after that rollback the question you retagged.

The right way to get synonyms made is to ask a moderator. If you don't want to ask on meta, do it in chat. If the current moderators are stretched too thin, then the solution is to <s>grow</s> elect some more.

Comment: Sounds like a plan.  (The Chat idea.)  Thanks very much.  // Any idea why I got two solid, helpful answers, plus lots of negative votes on my question?

Answer (score 3):

For creating tag synonyms the voting process doesn't work very well so I have been asking the mods on the Great Outdoors to implement them. I tried both asking in chat and raising flags and found both methods to be rather prone to miscommunications.

So I wrote a [meta post asking for 15 of them](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1147/march-2018-tag-rename-requests) and then the mods took care of it within two  weeks.

While I agree that is is seriously inefficient to post a meta post per synonym, if there are a bunch that are needed, it works to put them into one post.

Nobody disagreed with any of the ones I proposed, but if, say, they had liked 14 and hated 1, I would probably have just tabled the 15th to a later date.

Comment: Thank you, these are both helpful answers.  I wish I could accept both.